# Computer Vision in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, deep-learning, computer-vision, real-time

How can I introduce a pre-trained model for classification in an android app and see like in a real-time video view how it is detecting stuff?

I'm using Android Studio with Java and I want to use a pre-trained model (just for informative purposes - it is not important to the question - one of these more precisely https://github.com/thatbrguy/Pedestrian-Detection/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)

Are there any APIs to make this possible? Or is it another way?

Thanks a lot for your time! Any help is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: You may convert the model to `.tflite` and then use it in android for inferencing.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this guide to embed TensorFlow models in Android: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/inference_with_metadata/codegen -- this will generate wrapper code to enable integration on Android.

Note, there are a number of ways to export TF models, and you'll need to follow the export instructions carefully to ensure the TF model is what is required for TFLite inference.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll look into it:)